# How to frame a picture in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, imagemagick

I want to put a picture border(frame) around another picture. How can we achieve this in PHP using GD library? I also need to achieve the same using javascript/canvas and Image Magick.

A quick help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Define "picture border(frame)". You mean a frame IMAGE? A black rectangle?

Comment: I mean a frame image here.However a black rectangle is also required. I need example code for putting black rectangle around the picture as internal to the picture and as external as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using Imagemagick through php exec() you can use the examples on this website: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has a neat tutorial [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border).

For GD:

```
<?php 
$img = ImageCreateFromJPEG('img.jpg');  
$color_black = ImageColorAllocate($img, 0, 0, 0); 
drawBorder($img, $color_black, 3); 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
ImageJPEG($img); 

function drawBorder(&$img, &$color, $thickness = 1) 
    { 
        $x1 = 0; 
        $y1 = 0; 
        $x2 = ImageSX($img) - 1; 
        $y2 = ImageSY($img) - 1; 
    for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++) 
        { 
            ImageRectangle($img, $x1++, $y1++, $x2--, $y2--, $color_black); 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I think you didn't read the question or you don't understand. I need to use an image around the other image as a border. The function you provided just puts a line across. However, this is helpful. I have a question in it. Will it put the border internal to the image or external to image. I need examples for internal and external borders.